# Autowired is not injected in Mockito in spring boot

Tags: mockito

I have one test class. In that test class following method is called.

```
JanrainLoginResponse output = janrainService.authenticate(input);
```

janrainService is initialized like this

```
@InjectMocks
private JanrainServiceImpl janrainService;
```

Code in authenticate method:

```
JanrainResource data = janrainClient.checkLogin(input);
```

`janrainClient` is called properly in service class. In `JanrainClient` class apiDetails is intialized like this.

```
@Autowired
public JanrainApiDetails apiDetails;
```

But when i use apiDetails details I am getting null pointer exception. So how to inject this bean?
First level Mocking is working fine but in the third class bean injection is not done.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
@Mock
private JanrainApiDetails apiDetails;
```

By this, the bean is mocked and injected into the service (which is annotated with @InjectMocks).

Comment: Do you mock JanrainClient? Otherwise the problem lies somewhere else. Please provide more of your code.

Comment: And post the whole exception or debug into the test. What exactly is null?